# Is it possible to merge multiple gnome-terminal windows into a single tabbed view?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I had 2 tabs open in gnome-terminal and I detached them by dragging the tab away. Now I have 2 gnome-terminal tabs with my work present, and I would like to clean up my desktop clutter - is there a way to merge them back into a single view?

## What it's doing:

[image: What its doing]

## What I want:

[image]

Comment: Its definately a dupe. We should merge them with the screenshots to improve the overall quality of the Original Post.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There may be another, easier way to do this. But what I've found to work, is to activate the tab-bar in both terminal windows by pressing

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

and dragging the proper tab into one of the gnome-terminal windows. Then close the empty tabs until you are left with a single view.

## Illustration

Drag the tab into the other windows tab-group
[image: Drag 1 tab into the other window]

Once you have 3 open terminal tabs in a single view, close the extra, blank, terminal tab/window and you have achieved the desired result.
[image: Merged terminal view]

Comment: You do not need to create a new tab in both terminals btw. Only in the one you need to drag (i.e. in the case of the screenshots in your answer, you only need to create a tab in the right terminal)

Comment: This no longer seems to work on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 I can't get this to work either. Nor can I even split a tab by dragging it out in the first place.